# Cater for null reponse from endpoint response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method that subscribes to an endpoint to get a response. I have a case where the endpoint returns a null and I am trying to add a check for this.

```
public list: Array<any>;

this.GetList(this.getListRequest)
  .subscribe(
    (resp) => {
      this.progressSpinnerService.stopLoading();
      this.list = resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList; //error is here
    },
    (error) => {
      this.progressSpinnerService.stopLoading();
      this.handleServiceError(error); // error handling.
      this.serviceError = true;
    }
  );
```

Service response looks like this

```
{
   "header":{
      "statuscode":"0",
      "userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
      "wfpt":null,
      "paginationContext":null,
      "reasonCode":null
   },
   "accountNumber":null,
   "loanAdjustmentResult":null
}
```

The error I get is ERROR `TypeError: Cannot read property 'loanAdjustmentList' of null` on the line I commented above. Any idea what I can do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

1. add a condition to check whether the property is `null` before accessing it (which will leave `this.list` at its original value):

   ```
   if (resp.loanAdjustmentResult != null) {
     this.list = resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList;
   }
   ```
2. use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (which will leave `this.list` as `undefined`):

   ```
   this.list = resp.loanAdjustmentResult?.loanAdjustmentList;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `?.` operator like this:

```
this.list = resp.loanAdjustmentResult?.loanAdjustmentList;
```